# Mysql JOIN with LIKE statement

Tags: mysql, join

I have two tables one with cities and one with pois. I want find cities or pois from query string. Query string could be ABC coffee shop or San Francisco. The following query executes but returns empty set an suggestions?

```
SELECT cities.city, cities.state, pois.name FROM cities, pois 
WHERE cities.city OR pois.name LIKE '$queryString%';
```

Table: cities

```
+---------+-------+---------------+
| city_id | state | city          |
+---------+-------+---------------+
|       4 | CA    | San Francisco |
+---------+-------+---------------+
```

Table: pois

```
+--------+---------+-------------------------------+
| loc_id | city_id | name                          |
+--------+---------+-------------------------------+
|      2 |       4 | San Francisco Coffee Roasters |
+--------+---------+-------------------------------+
```

Update: Based on @Johan's answer I created the following query which return the results below. The results returned are correct, but I would like to also return a separate row like example A reults using something similar to example A query. I think a union is what I need?

```
 SELECT p.name, c.city, c.state
FROM cities c
INNER JOIN pois p ON ( p.city_id = c.city_id )
WHERE p.name LIKE '%San Francisco%'


+-------------------------------+---------------+-------+
| name                          | city          | state |
+-------------------------------+---------------+-------+
| San Francisco Coffee Roasters | San Francisco | CA    |
+-------------------------------+---------------+-------+
```

Example A query: 
!!! This query returns error **#1222 - The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns**

```
SELECT p.name, c.city, c.state
FROM cities c
INNER JOIN pois p ON ( p.city_id = c.city_id )
WHERE p.name LIKE '%San Francisco%'
UNION SELECT c.city, c.state
FROM cities c
WHERE c.city LIKE '%San Francisco%'
```

Example A result:

```
+-------------------------------+---------------+-------+
| name                          | city          | state |
+-------------------------------+---------------+-------+
| San Francisco Coffee Roasters | San Francisco | CA    |
+-------------------------------+---------------+-------+
+---------------+-------+
| city          | state |
+---------------+-------+
| San Francisco | CA    |
+---------------+-------+
```

Comment: all tables fields, available data sample and expected result would help to asnwer your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.name, c.city, c.state
FROM cities c
LEFT OUTER JOIN pois p ON p.city_id = c.city_id 
WHERE cities.city LIKE '%$queryString%' 
OR pois.name LIKE '%$queryString%';
```

alternatively,

```
SELECT p.name, c.city, c.state
FROM cities c
INNER JOIN pois p ON p.city_id = c.city_id
WHERE p.name LIKE '%$queryString%'
UNION SELECT NULL, c.city, c.state
FROM cities c
WHERE c.city LIKE '%$queryString%'
```

Comment: you should definitely have a join clause there, although Thorsten's post may be legal syntax, I haven't tried it.

Comment: Thorsten's way is how we wrote it back in the 1980's. But it implies a join.

Comment: I haven't tried it, too. I think the answer depends on what data the post author wants to receive, and how they are connected, if they are.

Comment: I updated my question to clarify exactly what I need. Can you please answer the question again.

Answer (score 3):

A few comments beforehand:

• Do not use SQL '89 style implicit join syntax, it's an anti-pattern.
• Use explicit SQL '92 join syntax instead, see the first example below.
• If `$querystring` comes from a user you need to escape it, see first example.

Here's example code:

```
$querystring = mysql_real_escape_string($querystring);
$query = "SELECT c.name, p.name FROM cities c 
          INNER JOIN pios p ON (p.city_id = c.id)
          WHERE c.name LIKE '%$querystring%' 
             OR p.name LIKE '%$querystring%' ";
```

Or maybe you want a UNION

```
$query = "SELECT c.name FROM cities c 
          WHERE c.name LIKE '%$querystring%'
        UNION
          SELECT p.name FROM pios p 
          WHERE p.name LIKE '%$querystring%' ";
```

**EDIT AS PER REQUEST**
If you use union, all selects involved must produce the same number of columns.
If you have no data, just substitute `null`.

```
SELECT p.name, c.city, c.state
FROM cities c
INNER JOIN pois p ON ( p.city_id = c.city_id )
WHERE p.name LIKE '%San Francisco%'
UNION 
SELECT NULL as name, c.city, c.state
FROM cities c
WHERE c.city LIKE '%San Francisco%'
```

Answer (score 2):

To do this with a join:

```
SELECT C.city, C.state, P.name 
FROM cities C
LEFT JOIN pois P ON P.city_id=C.id
WHERE C.city LIKE '$queryString%'
  OR P.name LIKE '$queryString%'
```

Comment: I think you'll need `OR (P.name LIKE '$queryString%' or p.Name is null)` for the `LEFT JOIN` to meaningful. Or you could make it an `INNER JOIN`

Comment: I think it's hard to tell without seeing the database schema

Comment: its not a function of the schema. See [Left join turns into inner join](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3256304/left-join-turns-into-inner-join)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT cities.city, cities.state, pois.name FROM cities, pois 
WHERE cities.city LIKE '$queryString%' OR pois.name LIKE '$queryString%';
```