# Select from table a where a value from a is on table b mysql

Tags: mysql, select, join

Table a:

```
field1 field2
x1     x1
```

Table b:

```
field 1
x1
```

How would I select on table b where field1 = to field 1 of table a?

What if the name of table b is field1 of table a, what is the syntax to perform the join as the selected table being a.field1

This is the actual query I am using:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tags WHERE id3='$value' AND flag!='w' AND visibility='t' JOIN tags.albumid WHERE photoid=tags.photoid AND visibility!='d' ORDER BY datetimep DESC LIMIT 200");
```

Comment: This is a very basic question. I suggest you read an SQL tutorial.

Comment: possible duplicate of [left join turns into inner join](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3256304/left-join-turns-into-inner-join)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on how complex your task is, you can either simply connect rows that have the same value:

```
Select * from a, b where a.field1 = b.field2
```

or use joins:

```
select a.* 
from Tableb b
join Tablea a
on a.field1=b.field1
```

In the first case you might have to filter again using the `Distinct` key word if you want to avoid multiple rows containing the same data

As for joins, there are different types. See eggyal's link.

Answer (score 0):

Learn about [SQL joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html):

```
SELECT * FROM tablea JOIN tableb USING (field1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.* 
from Tableb b
join Tablea a
on a.field1=b.field1
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming the fieldname to join is identical in both tables:

```
SELECT fieldx, fieldy FROM table_1 NATURAL JOIN table_b
```

if the fieldname to join on is not identical - or you want to be explicit, as you might have other identically named fieldnames - you have to specify these via the `JOIN .. ON` or `JOIN .. USING` directive.

Comment: Assumes not only that the join column is identically named, but furthermore that there are no other identically named columns.  This is dangerous, as it can break unexpectedly if one's schema changes in the future.  Better to be more explicit.

Comment: this is of course correct, although NATURAL JOIN is a very.. well... natural shortcut in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.field1, a.field2 from table a, table b
where a.field1=b.field1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from table_a join table_b
USING (field1)
```

Refer to this: **[MySql Join](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)**