# Can this SQL query be improved?

Tags: mysql, sql

There are news and categories. A news can belong to many categories, or have no category at all. I need to query for all news that don't belong to specific category (i.e. 2) (If news belongs to categories 2 and 3 we still don't want it).

It seems that I solved it this way, but I'm not very experienced with SQL, so will be very grateful for any ideas and critique. Sorry for maybe trivial and uninteresting question.

```
SELECT * FROM news n
LEFT JOIN news_cats nc ON n.id = nc.cat_id 
WHERE n.id NOT IN (SELECT news_id FROM news_cats WHERE news_cats.cat_id = 2)
GROUP BY n.id;
```

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: Seems perfectly fine to me; it's how I most likely would have done it

Comment: Replace all there WHERE with the subquery with `AND news_cats.cat_id != 2`

Comment: @marc_s Thank for your question! Right now I'm more interested in general theory. But I tryed it with sqlite and stuck on some problems, for which I maybe should create another question or read sqlite documentation :) Then I tryed it with mysql and it worked as I expected)

Comment: Can the news_cats column news_id be NULL?

Comment: @Mihai, that means category 3 rows are returned if both category 2 and 3 - which is not what OP asks for.

Comment: @jarlh I just noticed they are not equivalent,you are right

Comment: @jarlh Thanks for another good question and your time! No, I think it cannot.

Comment: @Mihai 
>>> Replace all there WHERE with the subquery with AND news_cats.cat_id != 2

You mean this: 
    "SELECT * FROM news n
    JOIN news_cats nc ON n.id = nc.cat_id 
    AND nc.cat_id != 2
    GROUP BY n.id; "

?
But it doesn't show news without categories. Will there be any difference if I change 'AND' keyword on 'WHERE' ?

Comment: @StasMakarov, just a note, if a NOT IN sub-query returns NULL, the NOT IN becomes false, and no rows at all are returned. You can either do NO EXISTS instead (which is "null safe"), or add AND news_id IS NOT NULL to the sub-query - if you want to be null safe.'

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM news n
LEFT JOIN news_cats nc ON n.id = nc.cat_id 
WHERE news_cats.cat_id <> 2
GROUP BY n.id;
```

Comment: Since we're talking about optimization: We could filter first on news_cats and join afterwards. But probably this will be done automatically by the optimizer.

Comment: You might as well write INNER JOIN

Comment: If an id has several rows, the original query doesn't return any of them if "news_cats.cat_id = 2" is true for one row. But your query returns that id's rows, just not that row.

Comment: @Mihai No, this would be a semantic difference. Left Join includes all news which do not have a category. Inner Join would filter them out.

Comment: @flowit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3256304/left-join-turns-into-inner-join

Comment: Yeah you're right. Nevertheless I would see it as bad practise to write an inner join instead of a left join when there is a where clause, because this could change, leaving you with the semantic difference.