# Left Join containing where clause INSIDE join

Tags: sql-server

Lets say we have the following table structure:

```
DECLARE @Person TABLE
(
    PersonId INT,
    Name VARCHAR(50)
)

DECLARE @Address TABLE
(
    AddressId INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    PersonId INT
)
```

And we insert two person records:

```
INSERT INTO @Person (PersonId, Name) VALUES (1, 'John Doe')
INSERT INTO @Person (PersonId, Name) VALUES (2, 'Jane Doe')
```

But we only insert a address record for `John`

```
INSERT INTO @Address (PersonId) VALUES (1)
```

If I execute the following queries I get different results

```
SELECT * 
FROM @Person p
 LEFT JOIN @Address a
    ON p.PersonId = a.PersonId AND a.PersonId IS NULL
```

---

```
 PersonId | Name     | AddressId | PersonId
 1        | John Doe | NULL      | NULL
 2        | Jane Doe | NULL      | NULL
```

VS

```
SELECT * 
FROM @Person p
 LEFT JOIN @Address a
    ON p.PersonId = a.PersonId
WHERE a.PersonId IS NULL
```

---

```
 PersonId | Name     | AddressId | PersonId
 2        | Jane Doe | NULL      | NULL
```

Why are the queries returning different results?

Comment: It becomes an inner join: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3256304/left-join-turns-into-inner-join

Comment: Because `LEFT JOIN` on personID does produce one match and PersonID is not NULL in that row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first query is not meeting any of your conditions. Hence it is displaying all results from the `@Person` table (Typical `Left join`). Where as in the second query, the `where` clause is applied after the `join`. Hence it is displaying proper result.

Answer (score 1):

First:

get all records (two) from `Person` and join `0` records from `Address`, cos none of address have `PersonID = NULL`. After that no additional filters applyed. And you see two records from `Person`

Second:

get all records (two) from `Person` and one of them joined to `Address` with `ID = 1`. After that your `WHERE` filter applyed and one of records with joined `ID = 1` disappears.

Answer (score 0):

ON clause defines which all matching rows to show from both tables.
WHERE clause actually filters the rows.

In the 1st query, it is returning 2 rows because LEFT JOIN returns all the rows from the left table irrespective of match from right table.

2nd query is returning 1 row, because for PersonId=1, @Address table contains a matching record hence a.PersonId is NOT NULL.

Answer (score 0):

Make it a habit to read your SQL query from the `Where` condition and then look at your `joins`, this will give you a clearer meaning/understanding of what is happening or going to be returned.

In this case you said `WHERE a.PersonId IS NULL` the `Select` Part must happen and It must `Join` using the following `join` criteria.

That is how your query is being read by your machine hence the different sets of results.

And then in contrast, on the condition where there is no where clause, the results on the Left table (p) do not have to exist on (a) but at the same time the results on (a) must be null but already they might not exist. Already at this point your SQL will be confused.