# How to do left outer join in spark sql?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to do a left outer join in spark (1.6.2) and it doesn't work. My sql query is like this:

```
sqlContext.sql("select t.type, t.uuid, p.uuid
from symptom_type t LEFT JOIN plugin p 
ON t.uuid = p.uuid 
where t.created_year = 2016 
and p.created_year = 2016").show()
```

The result is like this:

```
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|                type|                uuid|                uuid|
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|              tained|89759dcc-50c0-490...|89759dcc-50c0-490...|
|             swapper|740cd0d4-53ee-438...|740cd0d4-53ee-438...|
```

I got same result either using LEFT JOIN or LEFT OUTER JOIN (the second uuid is not null).

I would expect the second uuid column to be null only. how to do a left outer join correctly?

=== Additional information ==

If I using dataframe to do left outer join i got correct result.

```
s = sqlCtx.sql('select * from symptom_type where created_year = 2016')
p = sqlCtx.sql('select * from plugin where created_year = 2016')

s.join(p, s.uuid == p.uuid, 'left_outer')
.select(s.type, s.uuid.alias('s_uuid'), 
        p.uuid.alias('p_uuid'), s.created_date, p.created_year, p.created_month).show()
```

I got result like this:

```
+-------------------+--------------------+-----------------+--------------------+------------+-------------+
|               type|              s_uuid|           p_uuid|        created_date|created_year|created_month|
+-------------------+--------------------+-----------------+--------------------+------------+-------------+
|             tained|6d688688-96a4-341...|             null|2016-01-28 00:27:...|        null|         null|
|             tained|6d688688-96a4-341...|             null|2016-01-28 00:27:...|        null|         null|
|             tained|6d688688-96a4-341...|             null|2016-01-28 00:27:...|        null|         null|
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 44):

I don't see any issues in your code. Both "left join" or "left outer join" will work fine. Please check the data again the data you are showing is for matches.

You can also perform Spark SQL join by using:

// Left outer join explicit

```
df1.join(df2, df1["col1"] == df2["col1"], "left_outer")
```

Comment: I added result from using dataframe. I think the second uuid is not null from sql query is problem for me. It looks like it just perform inner join

Comment: Please check the following:-

Comment: Manually check you query with where clause s_uuid='6d688688-96a4-341...'

Comment: there should be two `==`, not three

Comment: Syntax varies based on language, for pySpark '==' are required and for Scala '===' (three = ) are required. Sample - df1.join(df2, $"df1Key" === $"df2Key")

Comment: There is an obvious problem with his code.  He includes a filtering condition in the where clause for a column from the right table of a join, resulting in an inner join.  This is a common beginner's SQL mistake.  Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3256304/left-join-turns-into-inner-join for more information.

Comment: @jmracek no, it's fine. What you are saying is true if they add a further `where` filter, i.e. something like (**in Scala**) `df1.join(df2, Seq("col1"), "left").where(df1("col1")===df2("col2"))`.

Comment: @GiuseppeBroccolo We don't disagree.  I'm saying that the reason why the version that uses SQL produces incorrect results, while his Scala code produces correct results, is precisely because the SQL adds a predicate on the right table after joining, but the Scala applies the predicate before joining.  What you're writing would be the Scala equivalent of his SQL version of the code.

Answer (score 8):

You are filtering out null values for `p.created_year` (and for `p.uuid`)  with

```
where t.created_year = 2016 
and p.created_year = 2016
```

The way to avoid this is to move filtering clause for `p` to the ON statement:

```
sqlContext.sql("select t.type, t.uuid, p.uuid
from symptom_type t LEFT JOIN plugin p 
ON t.uuid = p.uuid 
and p.created_year = 2016
where t.created_year = 2016").show()
```

This is correct but inefficient because we also need to filter on `t.created_year` before the join happens. So it is recommended to use subqueries:

```
sqlContext.sql("select t.type, t.uuid, p.uuid
from (
  SELECT type, uuid FROM symptom_type WHERE created_year = 2016 
) t LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT uuid FROM plugin WHERE created_year = 2016
) p 
ON t.uuid = p.uuid").show()
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need to use `LEFT OUTER JOIN` instead of `LEFT JOIN` keyword for what you want. For more informations look at the [Spark documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/sql-programming-guide.html#supported-hive-features).

Comment: I tried that and it still shows the result similar to inner join. There is no null on the second uuid.