# How to correctly combine multiple WHERE statements and multiple ON clauses when emulating a FULL OUTER JOIN in MySQL

Tags: mysql, constraints, left-join, full-outer-join

I have two tables. Global fishing data (capture & aquaculture). I want to combine by emulating FULL OUTER JOIN in MySQL.

Tbl_A - capture

- capture_id
- year_c
- species_c
- iso_code_c
- area_code_c
- environ_code_c
- qty_taken
- value_c
- symbol_c

Tbl_B - aquaculture

- aqua_id
- year_a
- species_a
- iso_code_a
- area_code_a
- environ_code_a
- qty_prod
- value_aqua
- symbol_a

This is complicated by:

- Tbl_A and Tbl_B are not related
- Tbl_B may not have a corresponding row

Tbl_A - capture

```
cap_id| yr_c| sp_c| iso_c| area_c| qty_c
     3| 2015|  TRR|    54|      8|   120
   678| 2015|  BOM|    62|     27|   0.0
    20| 2015|  TRR|    54|     27|   0.0
    45| 2015|  FRC|     7|     15| 86800
```

Tbl_B - aquaculture

```
cap_id| yr_a| sp_a| iso_a| area_a| qty_a
    78| 2015|  OTS|    32|     27|  6868
   333| 2015|  FRC|     7|     15|   550
   789| 2015|  TRR|    54|     27| 45000
   987| 2015|  TRR|    32|     27|    40
```

For a selected year (2015) I am trying to capture:

1. Tbl_A & Tbl_B records where (species, iso_code, area) are the same;
2. Tbl_A records (species, iso_code, area) that don't have a Tbl_B match; and
3. Tbl_B records (species, iso_code, area) that don't have a Tbl_A match.

Tbl_C - Desired Final Tbl

```
id| cap_id| aqua_id| yr_c| yr_a| sp_c| sp_a| iso_c| iso_a|area_c|area_a| qty_c| qty_a 

1 |     20|     789| 2015| 2015|  TRR|  TRR|    54|    54|    27|    27|   0.0| 45000
2 |     45|     333| 2015| 2015|  FRC|  FRC|     7|     7|    15|    15| 86800| 550
3 |    678|    NULL| 2015| NULL|  BOM| NULL|    62|  NULL|    27|  NULL|   0.0| NULL
4 |      3|    NULL| 2015| NULL|  TRR| NULL|    54|  NULL|     8|  NULL|   120| NULL
5 |   NULL|      78| NULL| 2015| NULL|  OTS|  NULL|    32|  NULL|    27|  NULL| 6868    
6 |   NULL|     987| NULL| 2015| NULL|  TRR|  NULL|    32|  NULL|    27|  NULL| 40
```

I have a query that uses a UNION to JOIN two LEFT JOINS:

```
(SELECT 
c.capture_id,
a.aqua_id,
c.year_c,
a.year_a,
c.species_c,
a.species_a,
c.iso_code_c,
a.iso_code_a,
c.area_c,
a.area_a,
c.environ_code_c,
a.environ_code_a,
c.qty_taken,
a.qty_prod
FROM capture AS c 
LEFT JOIN aquaculture AS a 
ON c.year_c = a.year_a AND c.iso_code_c = a.iso_code_a AND c.area_c = a.area_a AND c.species_c = 
a.species_a
WHERE c.year_c = 2015 AND a.year_a = 2015)
UNION
(SELECT 
c.capture_id,
a.aqua_id,
c.year_c,
a.year_a,
c.species_c,
a.species_a,
c.iso_code_c,
a.iso_code_a,
c.area_c,
a.area_a,
c.qty_taken,
a.qty_prod
FROM  aquaculture AS a
LEFT JOIN capture AS c 
ON c.year_c = a.year_a AND c.iso_code_c = a.iso_code_a AND c.area_c = a.area_a AND c.species_c = a.species_a
WHERE a.year_a = 2015 AND c.year_c = 2015);
```

But the query above is only returning a small sub-set of matched records

```
id| cap_id| aqua_id| yr_c| yr_a| sp_c| sp_a| iso_c| iso_a|area_c|area_a| qty_c| qty_a 

1 |     20|     789| 2015| 2015|  TRR|  TRR|    54|    54|    27|    27|   0.0| 45000
2 |     45|     333| 2015| 2015|  FRC|  FRC|     7|     7|    15|    15| 86800|   550
```

I do not understand how I am cancelling out the effect of the LEFT JOINS

Comment: It's hard to tell, but are you trying to do a `FULL OUTER JOIN`, where the result contains a row if either of the input tables contains that row?

Comment: If that's what you're trying to do, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796872/full-outer-join-in-mysql

Comment: I find that this tutorial here is of great help: https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/

Comment: Ug, I hate it when my OCD kicks in. Those squiggly tables!

Comment: `join_id = 10` is wrong, it's missing a column. Should it be `a_id = NULL`?

Comment: You are not clear. You have not explained when a row goes in the result you want. Please read & act on [mcve]. Also please format those tables correctly.

Comment: What do you mean, prevent? If you don't want to do something, don't do it. Left join returns inner join rows plus left table rows extended by nulls. Now--what rows do you want? You don't need to know constraints to query; they do not complicate querying. You just need to konw when a row goes in each base table, and when it goes in a query result in terms of when it goes in base tables. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33952141/3404097) & start by giving base table predicates. It is *good* to have example of inputs & desired output (not too complex)--why did you remove it? Was it ok?

Comment: What do you mean, "I have a working query" but "I know the ON and/or the WHERE clause are not correct"?? Please use enough words to say what you mean & describe everything correctly.

Comment: Re "cancelling out the effect of the LEFT JOINS" I already told you, look at what left join returns & decide what rows you want vs what rows you are getting from left join & then filtering. Read my comment about what left join does. Then look at your wheres. They require that there are no nulls for c.X. So you are removing null-extended rows. Solve your problem for inner join, then for outer join. This is part of finding a [mcve], which you have still not done.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [left join turns into inner join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3256304/left-join-turns-into-inner-join)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in the `WHERE` clauses. You are excluding the records where the 'RIGHT' table record is null.

```
SELECT *
FROM c LEFT JOIN a ON ...
WHERE c.year = 2015 /*remove AND a.year = 2015*/
UNION SELECT *
FROM a LEFT JOIN c ON ...
WHERE a.year = 2015 /*remove AND c.year = 2015*/
```

Comment: This answer does not explain why they are excluding & does not tie that to  the code. It is not clear.

Comment: @zambonee and (@philpxy) many thanks. The WHERE clause changes worked. I have to remove 42 duplicates from the capture table, but given 900,000 rows 42 is pretty clean.

Comment: I now better understand how 2nd year = xxxx was generating same effect as INNER JOIN. Not yet entirely clear on the 2nd LEFT JOIN logic. Will work on tomorrow.

Answer (score 3):

As MySQL supports only left, right and inner joins - you need to write two queries: 1) table A left join table B 2) table B left join table A. And then combine them into one result with help of [UNION](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html). Union will also remove duplicated rows in the result, so you will only have 3 types of rows in result set:

1. Row with data from both tables, i e A inner join B
2. Row with data from table A, where there are no matches from B. i e A left join B
3. Row with data from table B, where there are no matches in A, i e B left join A

Try:

```
SELECT ...
FROM c
LEFT JOIN a ON ...
UNION
SELECT ...
FROM a
LEFT JOIN c ON ...
```

Comment: This won't create line 10 in the result, which has both `c_id` and `a_id`. He really wants a full outer join.

Comment: Oops, that line is just wrong, it's missing a column.

Comment: not sure if a full outer join is it? Yes typo on line 10 (doh!)

Comment: not sure if a full outer join is it? When I tried full join initially query runs but stopped  when no row match in T2. That is why I tried left outer join. Because need to load T1 data even if T2 done?  c_id and a_id can be in same row. One table is captured fish, the other is aquaculture (production). Where the year, iso_code, area and species are the same I need them in the same row so I can sum the total global quantity. But where only caught or only aquaculture production for a given combination of iso_code, area and species for that year I need that to load as well.

Comment: @maksym thanks but union all stacks the data vertically. I need it to be horizontal. I think Barmar is right in that it is a join I need. Just can't seem to get the structure of the query right...

Comment: @Possbil, yes, union stacks all vertically. In your example "I need to combine the data into one table like this", you expect exactly this, isn't it? So in every row you have either c_id either a_id, but not both together. If it's not what you want - please update original question :)

Comment: I've updated my answer according to your needs, please tell me if you still have a question!

Comment: @maksym thanks! your suggestion gets me close. Have realised issue is with ON statement.

Comment: Right! Just in your case I would use "union" , not "union all", to avoid duplicated rows in result

Comment: I ran:
(SELECT c.cap_id, a.aqua_id, c.yr_c, a.yr_a, c.sp_c, a.sp_a, c.iso_c, a.iso_a, c.area_c, a.area_a, c.qty_taken, a.qty_prod

FROM fao_cap AS c

LEFT JOIN fao_aqua AS a 

ON c.iso_c = a.iso_a AND c.area_c = a.area_a AND c.sp_c = a.sp_a

WHERE c.yr_c = 2015 AND a.yr_a = 2015)

UNION ALL

(SELECT c.cape_id, a.aqua_id, c.yr_c, a.yr_a, c.sp_c, a.sp_a, c.iso_c, a.iso_a, c.area_c, a.area_a, c.qty_taken, a.qty_prod

FROM  fao_aqua AS a

LEFT JOIN fao_cap AS c 


ON c.iso_c = a.iso_a AND c.area_c = a.area_a AND c.sp_c = a.sp_a

WHERE c.yr_c = 2015 AND a.yr_a = 2015);

Comment: what I don't know how to do is set the ON or WHERE statement to allow for records in either table to be listed where there is no match with the constrants

Comment: so always need 2015 . always need where exact match for 2015 in both tables

But also need where 2015 record in capture table only 
AND 
where 2015 record in aquaculture table only

Comment: I also looked at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796872/full-outer-join-in-mysql.  @shA.t suggested query and expected result is what I'm looking for. 

But can't seem to find a SO example where also using multiple ON constraints.

The WHERE clause is because data tables large (join times out unless I limit query to a single year)