# Left join not working for t-sql

Tags: join, left-join

I have a lookup table with categories and another table with details, I am trying to get everything from lookup table with a left join but I am still getting only the ones that match . Below is the query-

```
select billing_medical_category_name,* 
from billing_medical_category bmc
        --left join UDW.billing_medical_claim_detail BMRPS  WITH ( NOLOCK ) ON bmc.billing_medical_category_id = bmrps.billing_medical_category_id 
        --where bmrps.customer_segment_number = 00744257
        --and cem_load_date > '01-03-2018'
        --order by bmc.billing_medical_category_id
```

Comment: Hi. Please read & act on [mcve]. That includes giving the actual code that has a problem. Also learn what left join returns--inner join rows plus unmatched left table rows extended by nulls. Here your where requires right table columns to be not null--so it removes any nulled rows left join added and "turns left join into inner join". Know what rows you want in the associated join every time you call left join. PS This is a faq. Always google many clear, concise & specific versions/phrasings of your question/problem/goal & read many answers. Add relevant keywords you discover to your searches.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [left join turns into inner join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3256304/left-join-turns-into-inner-join)