# LEFT JOIN on max id in where clause

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I'm working with a somewhat convoluted database schema to describe a person and their contacts (email/address/phone/etc) which could be simplified to the following

```
create table person(
 person_id number,
  name varchar2(25)
)

create table contact(
  contact_id number,
  person_id number,
  contact_type number
)

create table address(
  contact_id number,
  street varchar2(50),
  state varchar2(2),
  primary_ind char(1)
)

create table email(
  contact_id number,
  email_addr varchar2(50),
  primary_ind char(1)
)
```

What I'm trying to write a query for is the `max(contact_id)` for each contact where the `primary_ind` on that row is `'Y'`, if no such record exists I want the result to be null. I have a query that kind of works, however if there is no row with a primary indicator the person is altogether excluded from the results despite the left join. An example fiddle can be found at

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/af19f/1)**

Query:

```
select
 p.name,
 a.street,
 e.email_addr
from person p
left outer join contact ca
on ca.person_id = p.person_id
and ca.contact_type = 1
left outer join address a
on a.contact_id = ca.contact_id
and a.primary_ind = 'Y'
left outer join contact ce
on ce.person_id = p.person_id
and ce.contact_type = 2
left outer join email e
on e.contact_id = ce.contact_id
and e.primary_ind = 'Y'
where
(ca.contact_id = (select max(cma.contact_id) from contact cma inner join address am on cma.contact_id = am.contact_id where am.primary_ind = 'Y' and cma.person_id = p.person_id and cma.contact_type = 1) or ca.contact_id is null)
and (ce.contact_id = (select max(cme.contact_id) from contact cme inner join email em on cme.contact_id = em.contact_id where em.primary_ind = 'Y' and cme.person_id = p.person_id and cme.contact_type = 2) or ce.contact_id is null);
```

The results I would like see is

```
|-------------------------------------------------------------|
| NAME      | STREET                | EMAIL_ADDR              |
| Bill Ted  | Bills Primary Address | billprimary@example.com |
| Bob Dole  | Bobs Primary Address  | (null)                  |
|-------------------------------------------------------------|
```

However since the Bob record only has non-primary email addresses my query seems to somehow be excluding them. The schema is pretty set in stone and changing it would be quite invasive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I edited your code a bit:

```
SELECT p.name, a.street, e.email_addr
  FROM person p
       LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT *
                          FROM contact ca
                         WHERE     (  (ca.contact_id, ca.person_id) IN (SELECT MAX(cma.contact_id), cma.person_id
                                                                          FROM contact cma
                                                                          JOIN person p ON (cma.person_id = p.person_id)
                                                                    INNER JOIN address am ON cma.contact_id = am.contact_id
                                                                         WHERE am.primary_ind = 'Y' AND cma.contact_type = 1
                                                                         GROUP BY cma.person_id)
                                    OR ca.contact_id IS NULL)
                               AND ca.contact_type = 1) ca2
           ON ca2.person_id = p.person_id
       LEFT OUTER JOIN address a ON a.contact_id = ca2.contact_id AND a.primary_ind =     'Y'
       LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT *
                          FROM contact ce
                         WHERE     (  (ce.contact_id, ce.person_id) IN (SELECT MAX(cme.contact_id), cme.person_id
                                                                          FROM contact cme
                                                                          JOIN person p ON (cme.person_id = p.person_id)
                                                                    INNER JOIN email em ON cme.contact_id = em.contact_id
                                                                         WHERE em.primary_ind = 'Y' AND cme.contact_type = 2
                                                                         GROUP BY cme.person_id)
                                    OR ce.contact_id IS NULL)
                               AND ce.contact_type = 2) ce2
           ON ce2.person_id = p.person_id
       LEFT OUTER JOIN email e ON e.contact_id = ce2.contact_id AND e.primary_ind =     'Y'
```

What I did is: I moved referencing table you left outer joined from outer WHERE clause to inner WHERE clause, enabling them to be joined as you imagined (as LEFT OUTER). **When we add a where clause with a left outer join, it behaves like an inner join**.

Because of that, I also had to reference *person* table inside a subquery by using additional join of that table inside that subquery - where clause then consisted of comparing *contact_id,person_id* combination.

Please check the results and report with feedback if it works as you intended.

Comment: I will put here another question+answer which is directly explaining left outer join behaving as inner join when it's column is used in where clause:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3256304/left-join-turns-into-inner-join

Comment: That looks promising. I was trying to avoid inline views like that because I was under the impression that the inner query has to be fully calculated before oracle can do any optimizations on the outer (not sure if I'm making sense....). We have around 50mil records in this table so I was concerned about performance, but just from trying out your query it actually performed quite well.