# A query to get the products count that doesn't have requests

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join, outer-join

I have written the following SQL,

```
SELECT COUNT(f.productid) AS count
FROM   `product_list` `f`
      LEFT JOIN `product_requests` `r`
      ON `r`.`product_id` = `f`.`productid`
WHERE  `f`.`product_cat` IN( 1, 4 )
      AND `f`.`product_subcat` IN( '1', '2', '3', '4',
                           '5', '6', '7', '9',
                           '10', '11')
      AND `r`.`product_id` IS NULL
```

What I'm trying to do is get the product count where the product requests have NOT been made for a specific product category and product subcategory.

- product_list table - list of products
- product_requests table - list of requests for each product

The query doesn't give an output? It times out.

What could be the issue?

Comment: can you post the actual error message?

Comment: @mkRabbani : It times out. No error is given

Comment: "It times out."? What happens if you remove "AND `r`.`product_id` IS NULL" from the WHERE clause?

Comment: still the same.

Comment: According to this: https://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/ the left join variant should perform well for mysql (when compared to for example not exists). Could you post the query plan as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT COUNT (f.productid) AS COUNT
  FROM (SELECT *
          FROM       `product_list` f where `f`.`product_cat` IN( 1, 4 )
      AND `f`.`product_subcat` IN( '1', '2', '3', '4',
                           '5', '6', '7', '9',
                           '10', '11') ) `f`
      LEFT JOIN `product_requests` `r`
      ON `r`.`product_id` = `f`.`productid` AND `r`.`product_id` IS NULL
```

Your condition:

```
where
...
`r`.`product_id` IS NULL
```

needs to be in the ON clause, otherwise it will transform your left join, into inner join. For more details, please [see this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3256304/left-join-turns-into-inner-join).

Also, for optimization, try to filter **BEFORE** joining.