# MySQL w/ Multiple Associations Through a Single Cross Reference Table

Tags: mysql, associations, cross-reference

**Short version**: when I set a condition on a join table it is "contaminating" another join that uses the same table with a different alias, giving me unexpected results.

**Long version**: I can demonstrate the behavior with the following three tables:

```sql
# TABLE 1
CREATE TABLE `students` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(10) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO `students` (`id`, `name`) VALUES 
  (1, 'Sophia');

# TABLE 2
CREATE TABLE `classes` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `subject` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `year` varchar(4) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO `classes` (`id`, `subject`, `year`) VALUES
  (1, 'Math', '2019'),
  (2, 'English', '2020'),
  (3, 'German', '2020');

# TABLE 3 - A CROSS REFERENCE
CREATE TABLE `classes_students` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `student_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `class_id` int(10) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO `classes_students` (`id`, `student_id`, `class_id`) VALUES
  (1, 1, 1),
  (2, 1, 2),
  (3, 1, 3);
```

If I select from the Students table with multiple joins on the Classes table, it might look like this:

```sql
SELECT S.id, S.name, GROUP_CONCAT(C20.subject), GROUP_CONCAT(C19.subject)
FROM students S 
LEFT JOIN classes_students CS ON CS.student_id = S.id
LEFT JOIN classes AS C20 ON CS.class_id = C20.id AND C20.year = '2020'
LEFT JOIN classes AS C19 ON CS.class_id = C19.id AND C19.year = '2019'
WHERE 1 = 1
GROUP BY S.id
```

As expected, this returns all of Sophia's classes:

```
id  name    GROUP_CONCAT(C20.subject)   GROUP_CONCAT(C19.subject)
1   Sophia  English,German              Math
```

However, if I want to get every student who took English in 2020 and Math in 2019, I try adding conditions using both of the joins (e.g. `WHERE C20.subject = 'English' AND C19.subject = 'Math'`) and the query fails to return anything.

*What is going on here?* In addition to having a workaround, I'd love to better understand why this doesn't work! <3

**UPDATED**

As suggested in the comments, I've tried modifying the JOIN ON statement and adding a HAVING statement. The following query works as expected:

```sql
SELECT S.id, S.name, GROUP_CONCAT(C20.subject), GROUP_CONCAT(C19.subject)
FROM students S 
LEFT JOIN classes_students CS ON CS.student_id = S.id
LEFT JOIN classes AS C20 ON CS.class_id = C20.id AND C20.year = '2020' AND C20.subject = 'English'
LEFT JOIN classes AS C19 ON CS.class_id = C19.id AND C19.year = '2019' AND C19.subject = 'Math'
WHERE 1=1
GROUP BY S.id
HAVING COUNT(C20.subject) > 0 AND COUNT(C19.subject) > 0
```

But this strategy performs really poorly in my actual application, which is more complex and has 16k "students". (Query time is quadruple that of a similar query with WHERE statements.)

Comment: The condition must be placed into according ON clause, not in WHERE (where it makes LEFT joining INNER). https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=24a5e63a18ae167d714fa5f9ae70ca0b

Comment: Thank you @Akina! This strategy can be used to get the expected results, but it performs very poorly in my actual application, which is more complex and has 16k "students". I've updated the original question to clarify and include the potential solution.

Also, thanks for mentioning the idea of a LEFT join becoming INNER. I hadn't ever seen that before but I found another question that addresses it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3256304/left-join-turns-into-inner-join. This seems like a different phenomenon than what I describe above?